# How do I use AverageIfs with multiple conditions of cells containing text?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

How do I average the mean scale score of 2 ethnicities based on multiple criterias? If there is a NA for score, how do I exclude it?

The criteria are:

Same District name (col C)
Same grade level (col D)

Tried the formula AverageIFS(F11:F, C11:C34628, "$C11", D11:D34628, "03")

[image]

Comment: You may want to make sure that the range size and shape of each column reference is the same. To exclude can use ```“<>#N/A”``` as an additional criteria for your score column

Comment: Your formula is not right, it should have and even quantity of arguments and it got 5. Why is the first one `F11:F`? It makes no sense